# Jenkins Abort the build if Git clone / sync failed

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a jenkins job which does following activity one by one.

1. Clone Git freshly with timeout of 30 minutes and along with
   sub-modules. [Source code management -> Git]
2. Build the C# project which is downloaded.

Now, if the Jenkins job failed in step-2, it mark the build as Failed. Yes! correct.

But, if the Git clone/sync fails, it is still marking the build as failed. i Expect the Jenkins mark the job as Aborted.

Git clone fails for me due to Low connectivity and huge content.

I tried increasing timeout. there are known and new errors with Git every time. So don't want to do any workaround on Git side, but on Jenkins configuration.

Please suggest me how to mark build as Aborted (not Failed), if Git clone timeouts.

Comment: Are you using pipeline?

Comment: it is a free-style project. i am not using pipeline